# A (possible) Lie algebra extension of the Lie algebra of a foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, foliations

**Motivation:** The aim of this post is to extend the Lie algebra of a foliation to a bigger Lie algebra. We assume that a manifold $M$ is foliated by compat leaves. The Lie algebra of the foliation is the Lie algebra of all vector fields tangent to the foliation. We can reinterpret the Frobenious theorem as follows: Vector fields tangent to the leaves of a foliation form a Lie algebra.
**In fact the flux of these vector fields do not pass through the leaves. So the amount of flux passing a given leaf $L$ is zero hence this amount of flux is independent of the chosen leaf $L$.**

Now let a Riemannian manifold $M$ be foliated by compact leaves of codimension 1  foliation $\mathcal{F}$.

**Definition:** A  $\mathcal{F}$-uniform vector field is a vector field whose amount of flux passing leaves of $\mathcal{F}$ is independent of the chosen leaf $L$. This amount is defind as $$\int_L (X.n) dL$$ where $dL$ is the natural volume form imposed on $L$ via the Riemannian metric and $n$ is the normal field.

> Is the linear space of all uniform vector fields on a foliated Riemannian manifold a Lie algebra wrt the standard Lie structure of vector fields?

In fact this question aims to extend the Lie algebra of vector fields tangent to a foliation to a bigger Lie algebra mentioned above.

Comment: I would argue that the core point of Frobenius's theorem is the converse of what you said. That is, the important result is that any involutive subbundle of the tangent bundle is precisely that associated to some foliation. The other direction is effectively trivial.

Comment: @Callum  yes you are right that one side of the Frobenius theorem is obvious. But I think that the question of this post is not trivial. in fqct it would be a good ideq I change the title to "extening the Frobenious Lie algebra of a Foliation". I think that this title is more clear. the aim is to extend the Lie algebra of foliation to a bigger Lie algebra  so is the space if F-uniform vector fields a Lie algebra?

Comment: @Callum the title is changed.